# alter a dataframe by applying rules from a second dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Hi I have two dataframes.

Input data Frame:-

```
id   number      idsc                 mfd 
738  as6812      *fage abc van brw    amz 
745  786-151     *glaeceau smt sp     amz 
759  b0nadum     ankush 574415 mo...  admz 
764  fdad3-al-c  lib anvest-al...     amz 
887  rec-2s-5    or abc sur...        c 
64   00954       ankush pure g...     amz 
8    0000686     dor must die         a 
3    000adf623   bsc test 10-pi...    amz
```

Check Conditions Data Frame:-

```
condition      destinationfield expression                                b_id          
True           idsc             [idsc].lower()                            1 
[mfd]=="amz"   idsc             re.sub(r'\abc\b','a',[idsc])              1 
[mfd]=="admz"  idsc             re.sub(r'and \d+ other item', '', [idsc]) 1 
True           idsc             re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 ]',r'',[idsc])          1 
True           idsc             [idsc].strip()                            1 
[mfd] == "c"   idsc             re.sub(r'\ankush\b','ank',[idsc])         1 
True           number           re.sub(r'[^0-9]',r'',[number])            1
True           number           [number].strip()                          1
```

I am looking for applying each and every rule of condition dataframe on input dataframe and obtain a new dataframe.

If my condition is true then I need to apply it on all the rows. if there is any specific value apart from true then I need to apply that condition for a specific record.

Is there any better approach to do this in pyspark as the regular expressions are related to python. Instead of running it in for loops.

```
id   number     idsc              mfd 
738  as6812     *fage a van brw   amz 
745  786-151    *glaeceau smt sp  amz 
759  b0nadum    ank 574415 mo...  admz 
764  fdad3-al-c lib anvest-al...  amz 
887  rec-2s-5   or a sur...       c 
64   00954      ank pure g...     amz 
8    0000686    dor must die      a 
3    000adf623  bsc test 10-pi... amz
```

input data pipe separated

```
id| number|idsc|mfd 
738|as6812|*fage abc van brw|amz 
745|786-151|*glaeceau smt sp|amz 
759|b0nadum|ankush 574415 mo...|admz 
764|fdad3-al-c|lib anvest-al...|amz 
887|rec-2s-5|or abc sur...|c 
64| 00954|ankush pure g...|amz 
8|0000686|dor must die a 
3|000adf623|bsc test 10-pi...|amz
```

Conditions Data pipe separated

condition|destinationfield|expression|b_id|

```
True|idsc|[idsc].lower()|1 
[mfd]=="amz"|idsc|re.sub(r'\abc\b','a',[idsc])|1 
[mfd]=="admz"|idsc|re.sub(r'and \d+ other item', '', [idsc])|1 
True|idsc|re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 ]',r'',[idsc])|1 
True|idsc|[idsc].strip()|1 
[mfd] == "c"|idsc|re.sub(r'\ankush\b','ank',[idsc])|1 
True|number|re.sub(r'[^0-9]',r'',[number])|1
True|number|[number].strip()|1
```

Thanks,
Ankush Reddy

Comment: Can you give us dataframes we can actually reproduce?

Comment: Hi @user3483203
made changes to the question I think we should be able to  load into a dataframe now.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the "conditions" dataframe very large? If not then to achieve these transformations it would be most effective to just use pyspark.sql.DataFrame functions.
For example -- `df = df.withColumn("idsc", F.lower("idsc"))` would do your first condition.

Comment: I have around 14000 records in conditions dataframe.

Comment: @ankushreddy 14000 records doesnt seem much big. Is it possible to collect it in a list?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make your Condition Dataframe evaluable.

If it is evaluable, you could call `eval()` on the conditions and expression.

```
def apply_condition(df, df_condition):
 # write a function get_df_evaluable_condition which both does
 # replace "[any_column]" by "df.['any_column']" in createcondition
 # replace "[destinationfield]" by "element" in expression

 df_evaluable_condition = get_df_evaluable_condition(df_evaluable_condition)

 for index, row in df_evaluable_condition.iterrows():
    createcondition = row['createcondition']
    destinationfield = row['destinationfield']
    expression = row['expression']
    # just apply expression where createcondition is true
    df.loc[eval(createcondition), destinationfield] = 
      df.loc[eval(createcondition), destinationfield].apply(lambda element: eval(expression))
```

By the way, if the expression contains a reference to a column which is not the destination column, the last line of code won't work. You will need something more complex to achieve what you want.

I don't advise using this method if you don't know what your Condition Dataframe looks like. Don't call `eval()` on unknown strings !